# Do we experience wave function collapse even though we don't read the detector?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, measurement-problem, observers, wavefunction-collapse

In quantum double slit experiment would the the wave function collapse if we place a particle detector at the slit but do not read it and just keep looking at the screen?

Comment: Questions like these don't really have answers, because wavefunction collapse doesn't exist. Wavefunction collapse is a cartoonish feature of one particular interpretation of QM, the Copenhagen interpretation (CI). There are other interpretations, such as the many-worlds interpretation (MWI). Experiments can't even tell us whether MWI or CI or some other interpretation is correct.

Comment: @Ben OK then in that case does interference pattern disappear from the screen while detectors are detecting particles at the slits BUT we keep gazing at the screen?

Comment: @Ben Crowel: Any idea of "multiple worlds", quantum or classical, is much more cartoonish than the wave function collapse. Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: the mere existence of the entanglement between the detector and the flying photon is enough to remove the interference pattern on the screen.

Comment: Put another way, how does the detector know if it is being read or not. The detector sends out a signal - it is the 'observer's problem that they ignore it.